# Estou com problemas no touch da unity, não reconhece todos os toques e ao pressionar o player fica parado

Tags: unity3d

preciso de ajuda, qro clicar na tela e a cada toque mudar a gravidade

meu cod: (ta no update)

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    
    {
        eixo *= -1;
    }
```

mas parece q ele n ta reconhecendo todos os toques e se vc ficar pressionando vc para o player, tb n qro q isso aconteça, algm pode me ajudar, por favor?

Answer (score -1):

Ja consegui arrumar, se algm precisar algm dia, ta aq:

if (Input.touchCount > 0)

```
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            eixo *= -1;
        }
        else
        {
            eixo = eixo;
        }
        
      
    }
```